# Always exclude path in find command

Tags: shell, find, directory, alias

I have a directory whose contents should never be found by find, so I aliased find like this:

```
alias find='find -not -path "*.sync*"'
```

the issue is that find now complains that operators are not positional whenever I use something like `find -depth`. Is there another way to do this cleanly?

Comment: Perhaps something with `! -regex`?

Answer (score 0):

An operator named `-not` does not exist in `find`.  did you mean `!`? `-path` is an extension found on many `find` implementations but not in all.

Your main problem may be that all path name arguments must appear first on the `find` command line and if you add a path name type argument past that  expanded alias, you get `find` arguments in the wrong order.

A general solution for your problem does not exist since you may need to add further `find` arguments before or after the path to be excluded depending on the situation.

You may try:

```
find() {
    path=$1
    shift
    command find "$1̈́" ! -path '*.sync' "$@"
}
```

but this only allows one path type argument.

Comment: Or you could use `-type d -name '*.sync*' -prune -o`.

Comment: I have GNU find 4.7.0 and it has a `-not` operator. But yeah, that approach also came to mind, but would be kinda annoying to get working properly.

Comment: I also have GNU `find` and the `-not` operator is there. It functions the same as `!`.

Comment: This is still no reason to use it. GNUs `-not` is a method to create a vendor lock in. There is no reason not to use the `!` since that existed at least 15 years before GNU find has been written.